# Extending the std::exception class : program won't execute the appropriate catch handler

Tags: c++, gcc, exception

I have derived a class from std::exception:

```
class exc : public std::exception
{
public:
    exc(const text::_char *) throw();
    exc(const exc &) throw();
    virtual ~exc() throw();

    text::_char *m_what;
};
```

I have two wrapper functions to throw my exception type:

PS: dbg_out refers to std::cout. text is a descendant of std::basic_string<< char >>.

```
void throw_exception(const text::_char *p_format, ...)
{
    va_list l_list;

    text l_message;

    va_start(l_list, p_format);
    l_message.format_va(p_format, l_list);
    va_end(l_list);
    throw exc((const text::_char *)l_message);
}

void throw_exception_va(const text::_char *p_format, va_list p_list)
{
    text l;
    exc l_exc((const text::_char *)l.format_va(p_format, p_list));

    dbg_out << l_exc.m_what;
    throw l_exc;
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        throw_exception("hello world!");
        return 0;
    }
    catch(const std::exception &p)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My program crashes with this message:

```
hello world!
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I use gcc compiler (latest MinGW version)

My program does not enter the catch handler in the main function. It doesn't call the copy constructor of class exc. It looks like the code generated by gcc, does not recognize exc as a descendant of std::exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run it under a debugger?

Comment: Don't use va_list, it's horrible and not type-safe. Use variadic templates instead.

Comment: Do you know a good debugger for MinGW-gcc? I have not found one. I could use one!

Comment: I believe not ending a variadic function with `va_end` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, the text formatting is not the problem (the output is 'hello wordl!')

Comment: I'm not answering the question, I'm talking about C variadic arguments.

Comment: `text` is a descendant of `std::basic_string` ?? ... and what's `vlb`? A class? A namespace?

Comment: vlb is a namespace I use. Completely meaningless, but I forgot to removeit when composing the question

Comment: The variadic arguments seem unnecessary as does deriving from `std::basic_string` which it isn't intended for.

Comment: Without the `va` stuff, this seems to work in gcc.  I would be suspicious of `text::_char` throwing something that doesn't inherit from `std::exception`.  Posting a complete, self-contained example would sure make it easier. ;)

Comment: @TomKerr : `text::_char` seems to be a typedef for `char`, but agreed -- more code is needed. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question, my guess is that ‘text‘ is not convertible to ‘const text::_char*‘ and the C cast is forcing a ‘reinterpret_cast‘ and causing the problem. You need to define what ‘text‘ is

Comment: I found out what's wrong. I will post an answer to my own question later. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager your problem is on this line:

```
throw exc((const text::_char *)l_message);
```

You mention `text` is derived from `basic_string<char>`. There is no supported cast from `basic_string<char>` to `const char*`. So unless you're providing your own conversion operator in the derived class, you're kind of off into undefined/unspecified behavior here. Try changing the above line to:

```
throw exc(l_message.c_str());
```

Comment: I have an operator const text::_char * that does just that (call basic_string::c_str()). I found the answer. The constructor is called after the memory it copies has been deleted. l_message is long gone before the exc object is constructed (l_message is a local variable)

Comment: -1 `l_message` goes out of scope upon throwing, so the pointer returned by `c_str()` will be garbage.

Comment: @bert-jan: "I have an operator const text::_char *..." - Isn't it great writing `(const text::_char *)l_message` instead of `l_message.c_str()`? :) @ildjarn: The exception class should make a copy, so no problem there (unless the derived class constructor is not implemented properly).

Comment: @visitor : The definition of `exc` in the question doesn't have a copy-assignment operator, which implies that it probably just stores the pointer it's given (i.e., the rule of three is not implemented as it should be if the object owns the string). In any case, you're correct that the exception class _should_ make a deep copy, so -1 removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote on dec. 5th:

The memory copied by the constructor of exc has been deleted before it was copied. Access Violation guaranteed! I have learned one more thing about this wonderful programming language (what happens behind the scenes when you 'throw exc(some_deleted_memory)'.

<< end dec. 5th>>

This is not the real problem. The real problem is that gcc-compiler (with the options:)

```
    gcc -fexceptions -Wnoexcept -fno-use-cxa-get-exception-ptr -include .\pch.h -g3 *.cpp 
    -l libstdc++ -o vlb.exe
```

does not like exceptions to be thrown against the 'throw()' specifications of the function declarations. When 'throw_exception()' is declared as

```
    void throw_exception() throw(const std::exception &);
```

all is fine.

I have always thought that (at least software-) exceptions may occur at every call-statement, and the stack unwind procedure must be able to deal with that. I don't like the idear that I would have to specify what type of exceptions could possibly leave a function for every function I write.

Somehow, I should be able to specify that any type of software exception could leave any function I write, on gcc's commandline. But how? I will post a new question for this new topic.

Thanks to all who have thought along for me.

Comment: One more thing you need to learn - there are no guarantees. When you enter the realm of undefined behavior anything can happen, from crashing to appearing to work to having demons fly from your nose.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, you should have posted more relevant code and have people show you the light (e.g the constructor of your `exc`). Class `exc` seems to be particularly fishy. Normally you'd inherit from one of the standard exception classes that has the constructor taking `const std::string&`, and the implementation of your constructor would look like: `exc::exc(const std::string& msg): std::runtime_error(msg) {}`.

Comment: Don't bother with exception specifications (except perhaps `throw()` if you want to make sure no exception leaves the function). - It still looks like you are getting different results from undefined behavior: `void throw_exception();` means the function is allowed to throw any exception. `void throw_exception() throw (std::exception);` means only those exceptions are allowed to leave the function, otherwise program will be terminated (after giving you a chance to rectify the situation). No idea what effect the const reference might have in the exception specifier.