# command line option for gcc to specify any software exception may leave functions declared with 'throw()'

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, command-line

I am writing a program using gcc in c++. On dec. 5th I posted a question because of a weird problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392854/837803 ). When a software exception leaves a function declared with no 'throw' specifications like this:

```
int foo();
```

or this:

```
int foo() throw();
```

gcc-generated code will crash.

I want to tell gcc that any kind of software exception could leave any function I write. I think it is something like:

```
int foo() throw(...);
```

BUT: I don't want to write throw(...) in all function specifications. I realise that my program size will be bigger, but that is not a problem for this case. Also, I have read that the behaviour of gcc that I am suggesting, is an ANSI violation. But that is no problem either.

Among the many, many, many command-line options of gcc, there must be one that I am looking for, but I haven't found it yet.

What is the option I am looking for?

Comment: "gcc-generated code will crash." Do you *catch* the exception? If so, how do you catch it and how do you throw it? And if you don't catch the exception, well, what do you expect to happen? Uncaught exceptions means the program terminates. Generally with a "crash".

Comment: I catch the exception like try{}catch(const std::exception &p){}. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8392854/837803 . You can find how I throw and catch exceptions there.

Comment: ¤ Your DIY exception class is a problem (e.g. constructor does not initialize the exception text), and `text` thing you use derived from `std::string` is a problem, and use of variadic functions and va-lists is a problem. Here's how to fix: use `std::runtime_error` instead of your DIY exception class, and use `std::string` instead of your derived class. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: The answer you link to doesn't help. The *question* that it "answers" does. So at the very least, you should link to the proper thing. Your problem seems to be the exception object you're throwing.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach, when I add the throw(std::exception) specification, all is fine. The problem is not the derivation of std classes. GCC generates code that is 'supprised' by the exception popping out of throw_exception(). When I throw std::runtime_error() the program also crashes. It is not the exc class that causes the problem.

Comment: @bert-jan: This problem is unique to you. Other people are able to use GCC and exceptions just fine without specific `throw` specifications. It has something to do with the way you're putting your exceptions together or with how you're catching them.

Comment: @bert-jan: can you please post a complete example where throwing `std::runtime_error` crashes.

Comment: So why are you using exception specifications *at all*? You tell the compiler that "this function won't throw" and then you throw an exception anyway? Just delete all your exception specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take exception to this:

> gcc-generated code will crash.

This is just plain **wrong**.

A function declared like this:

```
 void func1();
```

If you throw an exception it will cause the stack to unwind upto an appropriate catch. IF there is no appropriate catch the program exits (weather the stack unwinds in this case is implementation defined (thus put a catch all in main)).

A function declared like this:

```
void func2() throw(); // ie no throw.
```

If an exception escapes this function then unexpected() is called. The default action of unexpected is to call abort() which causes the program to exit (Note: you can replace unexpected with a user defined function but it has to either exit or throw an alternative exception that can pass the throw specification (in this case that is not possible)).

The behavior you want is the default behavior (with no throw specification). Throw specifications were an experiment that failed and have thus been deprecated. You should not be using them anyway (apart from no-throw).

So you can get normal working code with exceptions if you define your functions like this:

```
void func3(); // Exceptions work fine.
```

But it is best to put a catch in main()

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        // DoWork
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)  // We can print a good error message with these
    {
        log(e.what()); 
        throw;                     // Not much you can do so re-throw for the OS.
    }
    catch(...)                     // Catch all other exceptions.
    {
        log("Unknown Exception");
        throw;                     // Not much you can do so re-throw for the OS.
    }
    // Catching forces the stack to unwind all the way to main()
    // Otherwise it is implementation defined whether it unwinds.
}
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer. The problem is propably that I passed the constructor of std::runtime_error() an object that wasn't really a std::string, but a descendant of std::string. This is getting all too confusing. I think it is wrong to pass a std::string descendant, where a const std::string & is required.       Thanx for your time!

Comment: @Loki: note that Visual C++ has never implemented the semantics of exception specifications except for the one specifying no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your compiler. With gcc default settings you can just throw stuff without having throw(...) in the prototype.

I use throw declarations in the prototype when I want to reduce the amount of throwable 'things'. So int myfunc() throw(string) will only allow strings (or a derived class of string to be thrown).

Comment: It doesn't depend on compiler settings. C++ does not require exception specifications in order to throw exceptions.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, it is really the throw(std::exception) statement of the prototype that is solving the problem. Remove it, and the code will crash.

Comment: @ bert-jan if you have these kinds of issues, it usually point to a more fundamental problem. @Nicol Bolas I only know gcc, so thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that you are throwing an exception of the type as [outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392237/extending-the-stdexception-class-program-wont-execute-the-apropriate-catch).

Your exception type doesn't work.

In `throw_exception`, we have this line:

```
text l_message;
```

I don't know what a `text` is, but I'll assume it is a string-like class. I will similarly assume that `test::_char` is just a fancy way of saying `char`.

So we have this stack object `l_message` which is of type `text`. Later, we have this line:

```
throw exc((const text::_char *)l_message);
```

Since you did not deign to provide us with a definition of `text`, again, I must make an assumption. I assume that `text` has an `operator text::_char*` defined for it which returns a pointer to a C-style string representing the stored string data, which is NULL-terminated.

Only there's one problem: *that pointer is owned by `l_message`*.

The moment `l_message` falls off the stack, the pointer returned by `l_message` disappears. That would be fine... if the class `exc` actually copied that string into an internal buffer. But it doesn't. It just stores a pointer.

A pointer which no longer points to valid memory. That's not a good idea.

An exception needs to be self-contained. It should *own* all of the memory it needs to do whatever it is supposed to do.

Also, you did not properly derived from `std::exception`. Specifically, you have to overload the `virtual const char* what() const throw()` method. Then again, I'm surprised it let you compile your code without it.

Comment: the exc constructor copies the string pointed to by it's parameter. When the exc object is copy constructed, the copy also copies the string. Forget the question I linked to for a moment. When an exception poppes out of 'int foo();' the program crashes. When foo is declared as 'int foo() throw(std::exception)', all is fine.

Comment: @bert-jan: I'm sure that's what you see, but that's not how GCC works. That's not how *C++* works. I use exceptions all the time, and I have never seen the problem you describe. You should take it into a debugger and see exactly where it is crashing.

Comment: @bert-jan:  If that is what you see then reduce the code to to the smallest program that reproduces the error and post it here. From your description it is most likely you are doing something wrong in the constructor/destructor of your exception object but without the code finding your problem is imposable. What is sure is that gcc is not acting the way you describe (it is your code that is causing the problem).